# Clickable TextView error

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

I tried to make clickable TextView like this

```
<TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fbtxt"
        android:text="@string/fbtext"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:clickable="true" />
```

And this in .java class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

TextView fbtxt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.fbtxt);

    fbtxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 

Intent main = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(main);  

        }
    });
```

but nothing happens, please help
Edit:
  Real code is:

```
public void onClick(View v) {  
            Intent fbclick = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com"));
            startActivity(fbclick);
        }
```

Comment: This works fine with me. This code is inside another class than MainActivity right ? otherwise you will not leave the activity ?

Comment: Right, but that was just test code, there is something about TextView, not about action

Answer (score 0):

Replace the

```
  getApplicationContext
```

with the java class from where you want to go to MainActivity

Comment: Thats not the the problem, that was just tesr code, real code is this

Comment: 'fbtxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent fbclick = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com"));
                startActivity(fbclick);
            }
        });'